# Dropdown onchange event not getting fired at all in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

No event is getting fired on changing the dropdown value. Please, can someone tell me where I can be going wrong?

**JS code**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    jQuery('#_ccounts select').on('change', function(){
        var acc = jQuery(this).val();
        alert(acc);
    });
});
```

Html Code

```
    <label for="_accounts">Accounts</label>
    <select id="_accounts" name="accounts">
    <option value="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Select an account..</option>
    <option value="1">abc</option><option value="2"DEF</option>               </select>
```

Comment: id is unique so id enough for selector and typo missed a in id selector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Id is **unique** for each element so id is not enough for selectors

> typo : missed a in id selector jQuery('#_ccounts ')

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  jQuery('#_accounts').on('change', function() {
    var acc = jQuery(this).val();
    alert(acc);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="_accounts">Accounts</label>
<select id="_accounts" name="accounts">
    <option value="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Select an account..</option>
    <option value="1">abc</option>
    <option value="2">DEF</option>               
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the `#_ccounts` not the right selector .Its not there in your html Better use direct `id` of the select `#_accounts`

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  jQuery('#_accounts').on('change', function() {
    var acc = jQuery(this).val();
    alert(acc);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="_accounts">Accounts</label>
<select id="_accounts" name="accounts">
    <option value="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Select an account..</option>
    <option value="1">abc</option><option value="2"DEF</option>               </select>
```